# Bedeutung von "Au warte"

Tags: phrase

Ulrike Meinhof hat in den frühen 1970ern in ihren Briefen oft die Phrase "Au warte" benutzt, etwa in positiven oder negativen Phrasen ähnlich wie:

- "Au warte -- ich freu mich auf euren Besuch!"
- "Au warte -- dass du das noch nicht bestellt hast ist schlimm!"

Die Phrase ist mir auch als Muttersprachler nicht mehr ganz geläufig. Wenn ich raten würde, klingt es nach "Oh Mann" im Sinne von: starke, emotionale Betonung des nun folgenden Satzes. So passte es bisher immer als Ersetzung. Weiß jemand mehr, kennt die genaue Bedeutung, vielleicht auch den Ursprung der Redewendung? Wird diese heute noch benutzt? Danke.

Comment: [Laut Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/au) ist die Interjektion "au" mitteldeutschen Ursprungs. Es besteht eine gewisse Ähnlichkeit zu "Au Backe!" Ich kenne "Au warte!" aber eher als scherzhafte Drohung: "Au warte, wenn ich dich erwische!"

Comment: Für mich (lebe seit 56 Jahren im Osten Österreichs) klingt das sehr berlinerisch oder zumindest norddeutsch. (Diese Floskel erinnert mich an deutschländische Filme aus der Wirtschaftswunderzeit z.B. mit Heinz Erhard.) Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass diese Floskel auch in Gegenden, in denen bairische oder alemannische Dialekte gesprochen werden, Verwendung findet.

Comment: <<Ich kenne "Au warte!" aber eher als scherzhafte Drohung: "Au warte, wenn ich dich erwische!">> So eher kenn ich es auch. << berlinerisch oder zumindest norddeutsch>> Meinhof war in der Zeit in Berlin und Hamburg, passt insofern...

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Ulrike Meinhof ist gebürtig in Oldenburg.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, dass es eine alte Form oder eine Dialektform von "Wart's nur ab" ist.

Comment: Hallo Andreas Hellrich! Und Herzlich willkommen auf German.SE! Die Frage lautete "kennt [jemand] die genaue Bedeutung, vielleicht auch den Ursprung der Redewendung? Wird diese heute noch benutzt?". Du gibst eine Vermutung über den Ursprung an, die aber sehr vage ist. Kannst du deine Vermutung konkretisieren und (bestenfalls) belegen und auf die anderen Aspekte der Frage eingehen? Das würde dein Antwort noch besser machen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich schätze, es gib eine Verbindung zu [DWDS: Au wei](https://www.dwds.de/wb/au%20wei), umgangssprachlich auch *auweia*. Das deckt die Verwendung in positiven Aussagen allerdings nicht ab.

Tatsächlich ist mir die Wendung eher von Unterhaltungen oder Telefongesprächen in Erinnerung, wo der Gesprächspartner nach *au warte* in seinen Unterlagen zu kramen beginnt, oder signalisieren will, dass er eben noch eine Denkpause in Anspruch nehmen möchte, bevor er seine Aussage zum Abschluss bringen kann.

Andere Idee: es könnte auch auch als deutsche Fassung von "P. S." gemeint sein (*post scriptum*, nach dem Schreiben, also ebenfalls später), wenn der Brief mit dem besagten Satz endet.